# Http Post Indy10 Error Delphi 7: Error creating SSL context

Tags: post, openssl, delphi-7, indy10

I'm using Delphi 7 with Indy 10.6.2.5459 to make a POST request to a server from time to time:

```
sParams := '?ultimaAlteracao='+FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD',now())+'T00:00:00.000';
FidHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
try
  FidHTTP.Request.Clear;
  FidHTTP.Request.Accept           := 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';
  FidHTTP.Request.CharSet          := 'UTF-8';
  FidHTTP.Response.ContentType     := 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';
  FidHTTP.Response.ContentEncoding := 'UTF-8';
  FidHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization','Basic '+EncodeBase64('xx:xx@123456'));

  JsonStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  JsonStream.Position := 0;
  try
    FidHTTP.Get('https://'+server+'/LinxImportacaoArquivo/GetSelecaoDadosMDMNCM'+sParams, JsonStream);
    DataString := JsonStream.DataString;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(JsonStream);
  end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(FidHTTP);
end;
```

After sometime, it begins to fail and returns:

> Error creating SSL context. error:140A90F1:SSL
>   routines:SSL_CTX_new:unable to load ssl2 md5 routines

If I restart the application, it works for sometime again.
I found some people who had the same issue: [here](https://www.programering.com/a/MjM3AzMwATk.html) and [here](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=247780)

From what I learned, it can be some other process which uses Indy to make a request that is interfering, and I quote

> It appears to be an issue with some type of static member
>   initialization inside the openssl library. I have 2 libraries, both of
>   them use the openssl library, let's call them A and B. When the
>   application starts up both A & B are able to successfully create a
>   security context. Later, when library B tries to create another
>   security context it fails. Both library A and B are module plugins to
>   our application so they both will load but if one is not needed it is
>   unloaded.

Indeed, my application has a lot of others process executing, making http requests, through indy10 or WinInet.

So, my question is: Is there some procedure I can call on Indy10 to make it initialize something that had it freed on opensll library?

Comment: On a side note, you should not by using the `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders` property to send `Basic` authentication credentials manually.  Set `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication=true` and use the `TIdHTTP.Request.Username` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties instead. And `UTF-8` is not a valid `ContentEncoding`.  And when receiving string responses, you should use the overload of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a `string` rather than the overload that fills a `TStream`, let `TIdHTTP` handle the response's charset for you: `DataString := FidHTTP.Get(url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that at unit IdSSLOpenSSL there's a procedure named UnLoadOpenSSLLibrary.
If I always call that procedure before my code, the error does not occurr.

Comment: Indy does not unload and reload OpenSSL multiple times, once loaded it stays loaded (unless you unload it manually), so this issue really shouldn't be happening in the first place, unless you are using Indy in a package and that package is unloaded and reloaded multiple times. It is really not a good idea to unload OpenSSL once it has been loaded, as it has internal issues with doing that, it is really not an unload-safe library.

Comment: @RemyLebeau too bad, cos I was getting the same error on attempting to send 2nd+ email over SMTP with SSL. This solution solved the problem.. for now.